# React/Ionic: Data from database shows undefined when trying to make Axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently facing an issue where the data I receive from my Firebase database is not displaying in the function I need it to.  The function I need the data in runs in `useIonViewDidEnter/componentDidMount` as I need it to begin polling when the page is entered and in an interval every 30 seconds.

I presume because it's run in the `useIonViewDidEnter/componentDidMount` the database is not retrieving the user's data in time before the function is run.  I am wondering if anyone has any other suggestions on either getting the data earlier or taking the weather polling from the `useIonViewDidEnter/componentDidMount` elsewhere so the data is filled in time?

I get the data via the code below which also uses an interface User:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState<User>();

useEffect(() => {
    const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(currentUserID);
    userRef.get().then((doc) => {setData(toUser(doc));})
}, [currentUserID])
```

But I need to access the data to request the weather:

```
useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
    weatherInterval = setInterval(() => {
        getWeather()
            .then(data => setWeather(data.data))
            .catch(error => {
                setError(error)
                return setShowError(true);
            })
    }, 30000);
}, );

const getWeather = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    return axios( {
        url: `http://localhost:3000/weather`,
        method: 'get',
    }).then(res => {
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(res)
        return res;
    }).catch(error => {
        return error
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I replaced the useIonViewDidEnter() with useEffect() but I also had an issue with the intervals doubling up so I added in the following return statements:

`return () => clearInterval(tempInterval);`

The updated code to get it to work and get the database information is as followed:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(currentUserID);
    userRef.get().then((doc) => {
        setData(toUser(doc));
    })
}, [currentUserID])

useEffect(() => {
    tempInterval = setInterval(() => {
        sendGetRequest()
            .then(data => setItems(data.temps))
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status === 403) {
                    logout();
                    return error;
                }
                setError(error)
                setShowError(true);
                return error;
            });
    }, 30000);
    return () => clearInterval(tempInterval);
})

useEffect(() => {
    weatherInterval = setInterval(() => {
        getWeather()
            .then(data => setWeather(data.data))
            .catch(error => {
                setError(error)
                return setShowError(true);
            })
    }, 30000);
    return () => clearInterval(weatherInterval);
})
```